# receiving post variables from an external source in zendframework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

i am working on a zendframework 2 project and want to receive post variables from an external source.

the source where the values will come from is a payment site (i.e world pay and paypal). i.e the return values of a payment confirming that payment has been made.

on the external site, i simply gave the URL of the web page that i want the information to be returned to:

```
http://example-site.com/payments/payment-made
```

then in action function on the controller page i did the following;

```
public function paymentMadeAction()
    {

        $contents = file_get_contents('php://input'); // read request contents

        $data = explode('&', $contents);

        if ($contents)
        {    
            foreach($data as &$entry) {
                 $entry = explode('=', $entry);
                 $entry[1] = urldecode($entry[1]);
            }
            unset($entry);
        }
       print_r($data);
     }
```

nothing happens though. i mean, i tested it but the values are not being received. when i went to the external source to check if my site received the information it confirmed that the information had been successfully sent

is there a special procedure that needs to be followed when receiving information from an external source in zend framework 2

would really appreciate any guidance or advise.

**update:**

below is a sample of the post variable that should be returned to the site; its a simply http object

```
 POST /fail?installation=XXXXXX&msgType=authResult HTTP/1.0
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
 Host: www.worldpay.com
 Content-Length: 973
 User-Agent: WJHRO/1.0 (worldPay Java HTTP Request Object)

 region=new+format+region&authAmountString=%26%23163%3B10.00&_SP.charEnc=UTF8&desc=&tel=&address1=new+format+address1)
```

Comment: what is the return method? post, xml, values on url?

Comment: hi dixromos98. its post

Comment: hi dixromos98, i have updated the question to enclose a sample of the post variable being returned to me.thanks

Comment: try this $post = $this->request->getPost(); then print_r($post);die; in paymentMadeAction()

Comment: still not getting post with the above? you can also try get $this->request->getUri();

Comment: Hi dixromos98. thanks for your help. i tried both and nothing is being returned. do u have any idea of how i can test whether the values even got to teh site in teh first place

Comment: can you try and see if you are even getting the request? $request = $this->getRequest();print_r($request);die;

Comment: you can also check if the request is post. $this->request->isPost() this will return true if post and false otherwise

Comment: hey dixromos98. i tried the $this->request->isPost(). and its also not working

Comment: $this->request->getMethod(); will tell you the method of the request. if this doesn't work i would assume that the return is not happening. Also when the payment is done does the page redirect to yours? maybe if write a step by step procedure of what is happening i might be able to assist you

Comment: Forget about ZF for a moment and var_dump $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST and $_SERVER, and you'll know where to find your data!

Comment: You can't var dump variable from an external post. You are going to need to log them to disk with either Zend Logger or a simple file_put_contents will do the trick tooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it in the absolute WRONG way, the correct way to get post(or query or route ) variables in ZF2 action :

```
$this->params()->fromPost();
or
$this->request->getPost()->toArray();
```